# How to make img height be dependent on container's height and container's width be dependent on img's aspect ratio?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

HTML:

```html
<div class="vertical-flexbox">
  <div id="card">
    <div id="image-wrapper">
      <img src="assets/myImage.png" alt="picture">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.vertical-flexbox {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#card {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
}

#image-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

`div#card` element has dynamic height equals to 80% of body height.

Height of `img` should be decided by flexbox and its width should be based on height to maintain original aspect ratio

`div#card` width should be dependent on `img` width to make it fit.

**How can I achieve this effect?**

Answer (score 0):

If `.vertical-flexbox` can be sized as `height: 100vh;` or some amount of `px` the image's `object-fit: contain;` should work as you need:

```css
.vertical-flexbox {
  height: 100vh;  /* <-- here some 'hard' value */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#card {
  background-color: gray;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
}

#image-wrapper {
  flex: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain; /* <-- to save aspect ratio */
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical-flexbox">
  <div id="card">
    <div id="image-wrapper">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/600/1000" alt="picture">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You know, whole point of using flexbox is their ability to grow and shrink, you can't just set its height to fixed value